# What physical processes govern the formation and shape of clouds?

Tags: diffusion, weather

There are many kinds of cloud shapes that appear in the sky. In fact, it's not unusual to see several different kinds of clouds in the same sky. What kind of physics equations and processes govern cloud shape development? I'm interested in a theory/equations rather than empirical facts about the isolated phenomena.

My guess is that the formation of clouds is governed by some kind of [diffusion-limited aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffusion-limited_aggregation). The smoothing of the aggregate (cloud) is then handled by regular diffusion.

Comment: I take it you've seen [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_physics)?

Comment: @HDE Actually no, thanks, although it seems this is an open problem. Well, at least I can search on my own now. Keep in mind I want a theory on formation rather than just empirical facts so Wikipedia's one sentence on the theory being an open problem, doesn't satisfy me.