# Are clouds forming above a certain height?

Tags: atmospheric-science

Are clouds forming above a certain height (300m+) and if they do, how are they staying above that certain height and aren't forming let's say at 20-30m from ground. What keeps them so high?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [What physical processes govern the formation and shape of clouds?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/194063/), though that question has attracted little interest. If you're interested in cloud formation I think it would be best for you to do some background reading about it and come back to us with any more specific questions.

Comment: My question is not related to how they form and their shape, it is about how they stay above a certain height and don't form near the ground too.

Comment: Check on Wikipedia regarding warm fronts and how they develop and move across any particular region

Comment: I think Earth Science is a better stack to discuss this.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because I think that you have not made sufficient research effort to find an answer using available resources such as Wikipedia. As John Rennie advises, I suggest that you update your question to explain what effort you have made and why those resources do not answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must know that atmospheric temperature decreases with height. As a moist air parcel rises it is thus continuously cooled and beyond a certain height water begins condensing and droplets are formed. A large ensemble of such droplets are what we call clouds.

If conditions are right then clouds form close to the ground too. These are called stratus clouds.

Comment: Clouds close to the ground are called "fog".

Answer (score 2):

@Zero is correct in their explanation, and I just wanted to add a few points.

Temperature, pressure, and relative humidity all play a part in the formation of clouds.  Both temp and pressure decrease with height.  As air ascends it expands due to the lessening pressure at higher altitudes.  When a fluid expands in volume, its temperature also decrease.  (See ideal gas law PV = nRT)  And as Zero said, the water vapor then condenses to form clouds.

Also, there must be sufficient water in the air to form clouds.  On hot, dry days, you may see very few, if any clouds.  The relative dew point (the specific temp and pressure, for a given amount of humidity, needed for water to condense and form clouds) will also affect the height at which clouds form.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Temperature _can_ **increase** with height as well: this is known as "inversion". See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(meteorology)

Comment: @Floris Well said!  Inversions are an abnormality which I didn't want to refer to and add any confusion.  But thanks for the additional knowledge.